# Xampp not recognizing soap and sockets

Tags: php, sockets, curl, soap, xampp

I run XAMPP. I did remove the comments from soap, curl and sockets. I restarted the server as well as my PC. For curl I see this.

[image: curl]

But for soap and sockets I get this

[image: soap]

[image: sockets-1]

[image: sockets-2]

I will only add relevant parts of php.ini due to the character limit I am sure this is the right file because I opened it via XAMPP.

```
;
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci 
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

Comment: When you say it is not recognizing them, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Looks like the bits you want are not loading, so probably wrong `php.ini` file. To be sure look at your PHPINFO output at the first box section for `Loaded Configuration File` that will tell you the path Apache used to get to the `php.ini` it is actually using

Comment: This is the right file. I already checked that line from php.info().

Comment: How to check the errors?

Comment: FWIW, you don't have neither SOAP nor Sockets installed according to phpinfo(). Your highlights are just static copyright info and an entry from Curl extension.